# Rails 4 Combine update_attributes(params.permit) with fix variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Through an API my models get updated with this call:

```
if @user.update_attributes(params.permit(:name, :phone, ...)
    format ...
else 
    format ...
end
```

This is nested in another if query and based on the result i would like to set a another variable in the same model. So far  i do it with

```
@user.update_attributes(variable: :value)
```

But this issues two writes on my table, which i am pretty sure can be 
merged into one, but i don't know how.
This is the whole block:

```
if test_for_something
   @user.update_attributes(variable: :value)
   if @user.update_attributes(params.permit(:name, :phone, ...)
     format ...
   else 
     format ...
   end
```

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the `value` into the permit hash and then run update_attributes only once.

just make sure this field is permitted.

this is just an example how u can do it:

**EDIT:**

```
params[:value] = value
```

if in nested in the model name then:

```
params[:model][:value] = value
```

then:

```
@user.update_attributes(params.permit(:name, :phone, :value, ...)
```

hope it helped you.

Comment: i added to my answer an example

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks for the example